# Full line trajectories plot for the solution of Second Order nonlinear coupled differential equations

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I wanted to plot a phase plane containing the trajectories of the solutions found by using 'NDSolve' using the initial conditions for x[0], y[0], x'[0] and y'[0]. The equations are:
x''[t] - 2 y'[t] == -x[t] + y[t]^2;
y''[t] + 2 x'[t] == x[t] + y[t] + x[t]*y[t]

The equilibrium point for the system is (0,0). I have plotted the stream plot for the system but unable to plot a phase portrait that would give me the full line trajectories of the system for different initial conditions. I am also looking for any periodic solution if present in it. The stream plot I got is given below and I would take initial conditions from it.

[image]

I get this by using the Parametric Plot of the NDSolve solution:

[image]

Kindly help in this capacity. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `StreamScale -> Full`? (See documentation for `StreamPlot`.) The stream plot you show looks wrong, but if you post the code you might prove me wrong.

Comment: Stream plot is not **wrong**  here ist he cose `StreamPlot[{-x + y^2, x + y + x*y}, {x, -1.5, 
  1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, StreamPoints -> Fine]` @Michael E2

Comment: That stream plot code produces the phase portrait for the first-order system `{x'[t] == -x[t] + y[t]^2, y'[t] == x[t] + y[t] + x[t]*y[t]}`, not the second-order one in your question. Is that the right plot then? (A system of two 2nd-order ODEs has a 4D phase portrait. Not something that can be easily visualized.)

Answer (score 1):

I can't find the way by using `StreamPlot` to do with second order ODE system, so here we use `ParametricNDSolve`.

Since there are four initial values: `x[0], y[0], x[1], y'[1]` or  `x[0],y[0],x'[0],y'[0]` or `x[0],y[0],x[1],y[1]`  etc , we need to set four parametric variables.

(Later we can use `Manipulate` to change the four parametric.)

```
Clear[sol];
Clear[Derivative];
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x''[t] - 2 y'[t] == -x[t] + y[t]^2, 
    y''[t] + 2 x'[t] == x[t] + y[t] + x[t]*y[t], x[0] == a, y[0] == b,
     x[1] == da, y'[1] == db}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 2}, {a, b, da, 
    db}];
ParametricPlot[sol[0, 0, 1, 1], {t, 0, 2}, 
 PlotStyle -> RandomColor[]]
```

[image]

```
Clear[sol];
Clear[Derivative];
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x''[t] - 2 y'[t] == -x[t] + y[t]^2, 
    y''[t] + 2 x'[t] == x[t] + y[t] + x[t]*y[t], x[0] == a, y[0] == b,
     x'[0] == da, y'[0] == db}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 2}, {a, b, da, 
    db}];

Table[ParametricPlot[sol[a, b, da, db], {t, 0, 2}, 
   PlotStyle -> RandomColor[]], {a, -1, 1}, {b, -1, 1}, {da, -1, 
   1}, {db, -1, 1}] // Show
```

[image]